# Слово надо и слово треба.

Tags: этимология, части-речи

В белорусском языке **надо** - это **трэба**. В русском **треба** - это жертва, приносимая богам. След этого корня виден в слове по**треб**ность, которое в какой-то мере является синонимом слову **надо**бность. Интересно было бы узнать о происхождении лексической единицы "надо", а так же к какой части речи её лучше относить?

Comment: "В русском треба - это жертва, приносимая богам." Жертвы? Богам?  

Требы - просьбы прихожан о священнодействиях и молитвах, совершаемых в храмах по какой-нибудь нужде. Основные виды треб - молитвы о живых, об усопших, освящение предметов и пищи.

Comment: Вероятно, мы с вами читаем разную литературу. Попробуйте копнуть немного глубже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Интересно было бы узнать о
> происхождении лексической единицы
> "надо"...

См. http://semenov.academic.ru/835 :

> **надо**
>
> Древнерусское – *надо* (должно),
> *надобе* (вовремя).
>
> Общеславянское – *doba*.
>
> Слово «надо» заимствовано из
> старославянского языка в XIII в. и
> означает «должно, необходимо».
> Первоначальное значение древнерусского
> «на добь» было «вовремя, в добрый
> час». Общеславянская основа
> встречается, помимо данного, в таких
> словах, как «добрый», «доблесть»,
> «снадобье».
>
> В других славянских языках этому слову
> соответствуют: в украинском – *треба*,
> болгарское – *трябва*, польское –
> *trzeba*.
>
> Производное: *надобно*.

Или http://etymological.academic.ru/2991 :

> **надо**
>
> Искон. Сокращение *надобе*, формы
> дат.-местн. п. сущ. *надоба* «нужда,
> потребность» (в диалектах еще
> известного) со значением «нужное
> время». См. *удобный, добрый.*
>
> *Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. —
> М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А.
> Боброва. 2004.*

==========================

> ...а также к какой части речи её лучше
> относить?

Название неустоявшееся. Одни лингвисты называют слова, подобные *надо*, *словами состояния*, другие -- *словами категории состояния,* третьи -- *безлично-предикативными словами…*

"Русская грамматика" такие слова называет *предикативами*.

См. http://rusgram.narod.ru/1645-1668.html :

> **§ 1653…**  Предикативы – это слова
> с модальными значениями
> долженствования, необходимости,
> возможности. Это – самостоятельные
> слова, не соотносительные с
> качественными наречиями и краткими
> прилагательными; например, *должно,
> можно, **надо**, нельзя, нужно,*
> устар. *надобно.*

Comment: >В других славянских языках этому слову соответствуют: в украинском – треба, болгарское – трябва, польское – trzeba.

Сербско-хорватское **treba**.

Comment: я б еще добавил  трефа--копье.  Эту требу недаром в виде оружия на картах рисуют.  trabs--копье--латынь.